# how to open new tab with iframe in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I want to open a new tab with PDF inside an `iframe`,

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function(outDoc) {
var win = window.open();

win.document.write('<iframe src="' + outDoc + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');    })
```

The problem is that the following code works wells in chrome, Firefox, opera but not in safari on windows.

> It gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'win.document')
```

I tried creating the iframe element first and then append its document, but that also doesn't seem to work, I also tried,

```
document.location.href = win.document.write('<iframe src="' + imageData + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

But this also doesn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK So after reading some other stack overflow answers, I got to knew that in safari it doesn't work in async mode, so you need to write `window.open()` before any of your service calls.

```
var win = window.open();

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function(outDoc) {

win.document.write('<iframe src="' + outDoc + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');    })
```